# How to restore the guest account in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Bionic Beaver?

Tags: linux, command-line, restore, guest-account

I have removed the guest account from the command-line using the command

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "[Seat:*]\nallow-guest=false\n" >/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf'
```

How can I restore the guest account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove config file which you created before:

```
sudo rm /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf
```

Comment: That is what I would do.

Comment: @IvanBayan ... thank you for the answer, it worked